# Too few arguments to function __construct(), 0 passed in La

Tags: laravel

i got this error when i try to run `php artisan migrate` i try many way but not success. can some one help me

```
   ArgumentCountError

  Too few arguments to function Spatie\LaravelSettings\Settings::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php on line 453 and at least 1 expected

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\spatie\laravel-settings\src\Settings.php:68
     64▕             $mergedValues
     65▕         ));
     66▕     }
     67▕
  ➜  68▕     public function __construct(SettingsMapper $mapper, array $values = [])
     69▕     {
     70▕         $this->loadConfig($mapper);
     71▕
     72▕         foreach ($this->config->getReflectedProperties()->keys() as $name) {

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:453
      Spatie\LaravelSettings\Settings::__construct()

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:189
      Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::resolve("2021_03_25_175607_general_settings")
```

Comment: I would delete my vendor folder and perform a new `composer install` and/or `composer update` just to be sure that the packages are properly synced. This seems like you are using the wrong version of the Spatie\LaravelSettings for the version of Laravel that you are using.

Comment: i already try the `composer update`. but after that it have like this https://imgur.com/a/zFaxe5C

Comment: What does your composer.json look like for laravel/framework and spatie/Laravel settings?

Comment: im new to this. i just wanna try to install the source from internet.  here the notepad link https://anotepad.com/notes/7aqt7nqd

Comment: here is the full source. can you check it for me. thank you https://mega.nz/file/LRgD1aaa#rJfg8DNpVZ0CxuXRq5swqJsc_IQjuXkITD8huccjUek Key if have: rJfg8DNpVZ0CxuXRq5swqJsc_IQjuXkITD8huccjUek